# Error from using shred on drive

Tags: hard-drive, shredding

I used shred to erase my HDD but after leaving for a few hours and then returning, I found the screen was filled with "Error failed to write to entry ignoring read only file system". I restarted my machine, now it gives me the 1962 no OS found error, as I expected. Was the "failed to write to entry" suppose to happen? and did it securely wipe the files as I wanted? this is the first time I've used shred on a whole drive, so I'm not sure what to expect.

I used the command:

```
shred -vfz -n 10 /dev/sda
```

Comment: Please add the exact command you used to do that via [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1164752/edit) to your question.

Comment: You need to use `sudo` when you use `shred` which is probably why you received the error. Also, you need to run Ubuntu from a live session DVD or USB or you won't be able to erase everything properly.

Comment: I used sudo when running the command, however I did not do it from a live USB but from an already installed Ubuntu. It seems everything is gone, but I'm not sure if it was erased securely because of the error. Either way, I will do it from a live USB next time around if that's the proper way of doing it. Also this isn't really a duplicate, this question is more about an error from using the command. I should probably change the title.